# Add _format automatically to all routes yml Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, format

I am building a REST API with Symfony2 and JMSSerializerBundle.

At the beginning, it was JSON-only formatted because I didn't have the time to implement XML for instance,

But now that I have this time, I would like to implement it.

I wonder how to manage the _format parameter,
Should I manually update all the routes, adding this parameter with JSON as default, or is there any way to update it manually ?

Basically, I have almost tens of routes like this :

```
my_rest_bundle_api_users:
    pattern:  /
    defaults:
        _controller: "MyRestBundle:V1/Entities/Users:list"
    requirements:
        _method: get
```

I just would not have to edit all these routes manually, if possible !

```
my_rest_bundle_api_users:
    pattern:  /.{_format}
    defaults:
        _controller: "MyRestBundle:V1/Entities/Users:list"
        _format: json
    requirements:
        _method: get
        _format: json|xml
```

Comment: Just an untested hunch: Can you try importing all json based routes the same way as adding a prefix? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes  Probably you can add _defaults there too.

Comment: All these routes are indeed imported with prefixes, such as /api/v1, and I am wondering if there is a suffix-like way to manage it, but I do not think...

Comment: Try adding the _deafults node there also, and see if it gets imported.